# Why this is happening with C++ destructor?

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I'm starting to learn class in c++ , so the idea destructor is being a bit confusing to me . Here's a sample code that I tried to understand how destructor is called.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class dyna
{
int *p;
public:
    dyna(int i);
    ~dyna() { delete(p); cout<<"Freeing"<<endl; }
    int get()
    {
    return *p;
    }
};

dyna::dyna(int i)
{
    p = new int;
    *p = i;
}

int neg(dyna ob)
{
    return -ob.get();
}

int main()
{
    dyna o(-10);
    cout<<o.get()<<endl;
    cout<<neg(o)<<endl;

    dyna o2(20);
    cout<<o2.get()<<endl;
    cout<<neg(o2)<<endl;

    cout<<o.get()<<endl;
    cout<<neg(o)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
-10
10
Freeing
20
-20
Freeing
20
-20
Freeing
Freeing
Freeing
```

My question is that why it's showing last 3 "Freeing"? I understand first of them for being out of scope of `int neg(dyna ob)` . But why the last two one ? Please help.

Comment: I would expect 5 executions of the destructor. You have 2 objects and 3 temporaries.

Comment: Your "neg(dyna ob)" function is pass by value so it creates a copy of your object.  Try "neg(const dyna &ob)" to pass by reference.

Comment: Passing by value will create a temporary objects thus a constructor/destructor are invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not pass `dyna ob` into `neg` by reference or address, a `dyna` with scope local to the function is created and destroyed each time you call it. This produces the first 3 `Freeing`s you see printed out. The last 2 are when `o` and `o2` are destroyed in `main`.

Comment: And this is causing undefined behavior, since the destructor of the copy frees the pointer, but the original object is still using it, and then frees it again when it's destroyed.

Comment: @Garrett Thanks for your answer !!! Just got it now :)

Comment: @ArifHamim please review the duplicate. It is very important that you understand the rule of 3 / 5 / 0 to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: @drescherjm Okay, Thanks for the referrence !!